# I tried running a code on jupyter returned as error

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-e20bfc399896> in <module>()
----> 1 collection = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BBKdatasciencetaster/DS/main/data/paintings.csv", index_col=0)
      2 collection.head() # Returns the first five rows

NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
```

Comment: The section of your notebook where you ```import pandas as pd ``` has not been executed

Answer (score 0):

add the below code at the beginning of your cell:

```
import pandas as pd
```

then re-execute the cell. the problem must be solved.